# what is the function of satellite in a chromosome?

Tags: molecular-genetics

What is the specific function of a satellite in a chromosome ? How are sat-chromosomes different from others ? On molecular basis, what are the functional advantages of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are at least 2 SAT chromosomes in each diploid nucleus. They
>   play a vital role in the formation of the nucleolus after cell
>   division is completed.
>
> In humans, chromosomes number 13, 14, 15, 21 and 22 are examples of
>   SAT chromosomes.

cuted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_chromosome